# How do I decompress large files using Zstd-jni and Byte Buffers

Tags: java, performance, bytebuffer, zstd

I am trying to decompress a lot of 40 MB+ files as I download them in parallel using ByteBuffers and Channels.  I am getting better throughput by using Channels than I do by using Streams and we need this to be a very high throughput system as we need to process 40 TB of files every day and this part of the process is currently the bottleneck.  The files are compressed with [zstd-jni](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni).  Zstd-jni has api's for decompressing byte buffers but I get an error when I use them.  How do I decompress a byte buffer at a time using zstd-jni?

I found these examples in their tests, but unless I am missing something the examples using ByteBuffers seem to assume the entire input file fits in one ByteBuffer:
https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/master/src/test/scala/Zstd.scala

Below is my code for compressing and decompressing files.  The compression code works great, but the decompression code then fails with an error of -70.

```
public static long compressFile(String inFile, String outFolder, ByteBuffer inBuffer, ByteBuffer compressedBuffer, int compressionLevel) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(inFile);
    File outFile = new File(outFolder, file.getName() + ".zs");
    long numBytes = 0l;

    try (RandomAccessFile inRaFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        RandomAccessFile outRaFile = new RandomAccessFile(outFile, "rw");
                FileChannel inChannel = inRaFile.getChannel();
                FileChannel outChannel = outRaFile.getChannel()) {
        inBuffer.clear();
        while(inChannel.read(inBuffer) > 0) {
            inBuffer.flip();
            compressedBuffer.clear();

            long compressedSize = Zstd.compressDirectByteBuffer(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.capacity(), inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.limit(), compressionLevel);
            numBytes+=compressedSize;
            compressedBuffer.position((int)compressedSize);
            compressedBuffer.flip();
            outChannel.write(compressedBuffer);
            inBuffer.clear(); 
        }
    }

    return numBytes;
}

public static long decompressFile(String originalFilePath, String inFolder, ByteBuffer inBuffer, ByteBuffer decompressedBuffer) throws IOException {
    File outFile = new File(originalFilePath);
    File inFile = new File(inFolder, outFile.getName() + ".zs");
    outFile = new File(inFolder, outFile.getName());

    long numBytes = 0l;

    try (RandomAccessFile inRaFile = new RandomAccessFile(inFile, "r");
        RandomAccessFile outRaFile = new RandomAccessFile(outFile, "rw");
                FileChannel inChannel = inRaFile.getChannel();
                FileChannel outChannel = outRaFile.getChannel()) {

        inBuffer.clear();

        while(inChannel.read(inBuffer) > 0) {
            inBuffer.flip();
            decompressedBuffer.clear();
            long compressedSize = Zstd.decompressDirectByteBuffer(decompressedBuffer, 0, decompressedBuffer.capacity(), inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.limit());
            System.out.println(Zstd.isError(compressedSize) + " " + compressedSize);
            numBytes+=compressedSize;
            decompressedBuffer.position((int)compressedSize);
            decompressedBuffer.flip();
            outChannel.write(decompressedBuffer);
            inBuffer.clear(); 
        }
    }

    return numBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the static methods you use in your example assume the whole compressed file fits in one ByteBuffer. As far as I understand your requirements, you need streaming decompression using ByteBuffers.  ZstdDirectBufferDecompressingStream already provides this:

https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.luben/zstd-jni/1.3.7-1/com/github/luben/zstd/ZstdDirectBufferDecompressingStream.html

and here is an example how to use it (from the tests):

https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/master/src/test/scala/Zstd.scala#L261-L302

but you have also to subclass it and override the "refill" method.

EDIT: here is a new test I just added that has exactly the same structure as your question - moving data beteen channels:

https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/master/src/test/scala/Zstd.scala#L540-L586